# Why does %>% unnest() produce twice the number of rows in R

Tags: r

When I run

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

fitted.models<-df %>% nest(data = -event) %>% mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(EC..mS.~Flow, data = .)), tidied = map(model, tidy))
```

I get the desired number of rows (22, matches the number of different levels of 'event') in the output dataframe. But I would like to 'unnest' the tided column so they are additional columns in fitted.models. But when I run

```
fitted.models<-df %>% nest(data = -event) %>% mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(EC..mS.~Flow, data = .)), tidied = map(model, tidy)) %>% unnest(tidied)
```

the columns are unpacked but each event is listed twice (total number of rows now 44). What am I missing?

My dataframe:

```
df<-structure(list(EC..mS. = c(0.71, 0.828, 1.032, 1.134, 1.13, 1.205, 
1.221, 0.756, 0.823, 0.731, 0.75, 0.88, 0.942, 1.027, 0.993, 
0.78, 0.866, 0.745, 0.82, 0.821, 0.827, 0.949, 0.961, 1.012, 
1.046, 0.827, 0.824, 0.534, 0.553, 0.75, 0.876, 0.953, 0.934, 
0.973, 0.999, 0.54, 0.602, 0.808, 0.979, 1.044, 1.138, 1.166, 
1.155, 1.169, 1.202, 1.1, 0.882, 0.842, 0.88, 0.926, 0.986, 1.087, 
1.157, 0.785, 0.756, 0.721, 0.708, 0.676, 0.677, 0.672, 0.689, 
0.712, 0.797, 0.936, 0.863, 0.648, 0.537, 0.582, 0.789, 1.126, 
1.26, 1.4, 0.762, 0.572, 0.646, 0.535, 0.486, 0.475, 0.581, 0.693, 
0.788, 0.871, 0.839, 0.811, 0.848, 0.838, 0.87, 0.915, 0.939, 
0.977, 0.973, 0.981, 1.232, 0.811, 0.824, 0.752, 0.683, 0.684, 
0.686, 0.685, 0.705, 0.731, 0.931, 0.993, 1.019, 1.05, 1.067, 
1.032, 1.067, 1.087, 1.097, 1.108, 1.068, 1.095, 0.991, 1.007, 
1.02, 1.023, 1.019, 1.018, 1.013, 1.013, 1.008, 1.018, 1.032, 
1.029, 1.058, 1.745, 1.675, 1.67, 1.631, 1.617, 1.544, 1.477, 
1.455, 1.433, 1.431, 1.433, 1.426, 1.222, 1.158, 1.156, 1.15, 
1.136, 1.125, 1.036, 0.989, 0.989, 0.98, 0.974, 0.968, 0.952, 
0.945, 0.942, 0.941, 0.934, 0.91, 0.905, 0.917, 0.93, 0.939, 
0.946, 0.955, 0.967, 0.973, 0.979, 0.988, 0.951, 0.944, 0.931, 
0.935, 0.939, 0.941, 0.938, 0.927, 0.92, 0.909, 0.897, 1.001, 
0.908, 0.905, 0.914, 0.99, 0.956, 1.042, 1.047, 1.007, 0.999, 
1.017, 1.03, 1.027, 1.021, 1.018, 1.008, 0.974, 0.965, 0.969, 
1.038, 1.057, 1.061, 1.053, 1.048, 1.078, 1.096, 1.093, 1.088, 
1.09, 1.162, 1.152, 0.819, 0.707, 0.679, 0.685, 0.692, 0.702, 
0.706, 0.711, 0.711, 0.714, 0.834, 0.819, 1.404, 1.305, 1.17, 
1.057, 1.013, 1.004, 1.015, 1.03, 1.047, 1.061, 1.38, 1.43, 0.988, 
0.63, 0.566, 0.531, 0.533, 0.584, 0.653, 0.742, 0.777, 0.818, 
0.86, 0.884, 0.896, 0.84, 0.796, 0.744, 0.665, 0.61, 0.581, 0.42, 
0.421, 0.428, 0.433, 0.456, 0.484, 0.527, 0.571, 0.616, 0.634, 
0.636, 0.633, 0.651, 0.681, 0.72, 0.764, 0.857, 1.1162, 1.327, 
0.73, 0.619, 0.613, 0.626, 0.657, 0.708, 0.747, 0.783, 0.804, 
0.822, 0.828, 0.836, 0.826, 0.818, 0.764, 0.754, 0.709, 0.678, 
0.658, 0.492, 0.424, 0.424, 0.442, 0.454, 0.477, 0.492, 0.512, 
0.521, 0.521, 0.526, 0.537, 0.546, 0.574, 0.586, 0.589, 0.604, 
0.62, 0.639, 0.637, 0.595, 0.677, 0.689, 0.681, 1.254, 1.207, 
1.2, 1.181, 1.154, 1.221, 1.171, 1.164, 1.088, 1.123, 1.132, 
1.106, 1.037, 0.994, 0.93, 0.924, 0.934, 0.936, 0.945, 0.97, 
1.001, 1.017, 0.978, 0.965, 0.975, 0.988, 1.009, 1.047, 1.097, 
1.16, 1.315, 0.696, 0.684, 0.655, 0.671, 0.662, 0.668, 0.651, 
0.682, 0.685, 0.682, 0.654, 0.65, 0.659, 0.666, 0.669, 0.672, 
0.665, 0.64, 0.62, 0.596, 0.58, 0.591, 0.593, 0.592, 0.588, 0.584, 
0.579, 0.583, 0.581, 0.581, 0.576, 0.581, 1.07, 1.134, 1.198, 
1.224, 1.227, 1.171, 0.979, 0.972, 1.278, 1.079, 1.144, 1.221, 
1.374, 1.437, 1.501, 1.538, 1.599, 1.619, 0.753, 0.674, 0.682, 
0.676, 0.674, 0.697, 0.732, 0.739, 0.76, 0.762, 0.716, 0.719, 
0.736, 0.785, 0.8, 0.796, 0.856, 0.887, 0.904, 1.349, 0.895, 
0.854, 0.914, 0.994, 0.993, 0.986, 0.877, 0.843, 0.833, 0.809, 
0.827, 0.848, 0.854, 0.836, 0.806, 0.795, 0.805, 0.803, 1.156, 
1.003, 1.036, 1.106, 1.038, 1.064, 1.102, 1.159, 1.234, 1.313, 
1.423, 1.49, 0.926, 0.707, 0.706, 0.699, 0.68, 0.672, 0.655, 
0.644, 0.636, 0.637, 0.627, 0.615, 0.614, 0.614, 0.599, 0.598, 
0.596, 0.596, 0.583, 0.589, 0.601, 0.619, 0.628, 0.646, 0.651, 
0.669, 0.699, 0.733, 0.762, 0.786, 0.794, 1.023, 0.951, 0.701, 
0.733, 0.705, 0.681, 0.711, 0.738, 0.743, 0.76, 0.756, 0.799, 
0.834, 0.908, 1.012, 1.066, 1.136, 1.245, 0.876, 0.614, 0.588, 
0.594, 0.573, 0.567, 0.565, 0.564, 0.563, 0.558, 0.563, 0.567, 
0.58, 0.586, 0.605, 0.661, 1.879, 1.161, 1.084, 1.033, 1.071, 
1.115, 1.171, 1.268, 1.253, 1.004, 1.058, 1.117, 1.185, 1.232, 
1.294, 1.376, 1.434, 1.036, 1.134, 1.176, 1.241, 1.308, 1.2, 
1.256, 1.372, 1.572, 1.01, 0.962, 0.952, 0.979, 0.992, 1.062, 
0.939, 0.964, 0.996, 1.042, 1.093, 1.152, 0.969, 1.018, 1.071, 
1.047, 1.083, 1.116, 1.231, 0.939, 1.087, 0.871, 0.864, 0.949, 
1.026, 1.083, 1.171, 1.266, 0.997, 0.893, 0.806, 0.832, 0.876, 
0.935, 1.014, 1.531, 0.949, 1.147, 1.385, 1.248, 0.831, 1.015, 
0.992, 1.305, 1.169, 1.05, 1.168, 0.78, 0.706, 0.667, 0.611, 
0.662, 0.713, 0.749, 0.775, 0.818, 0.817, 0.805, 0.792, 0.775, 
0.596, 0.594, 0.645, 0.652, 0.946, 0.982, 0.657, 0.613, 0.612, 
0.64, 0.665, 0.689, 0.712, 0.699, 0.7, 0.601, 0.569, 0.579, 0.559, 
0.546, 0.52, 0.531, 0.555, 0.807, 1.029, 0.753, 0.632, 0.672, 
0.708, 0.793, 0.853, 0.913, 1.004, 1.114, 1.201, 0.841, 0.591, 
0.626, 0.683, 0.737, 0.791, 0.862, 0.917, 0.94, 0.406, 0.459, 
0.522, 0.563, 0.597, 0.627, 1.052, 0.446, 0.472, 0.488, 0.52, 
0.564, 0.582, 0.598, 0.622, 0.653, 0.82), Flow = c(5.08881355932203, 
2.39186440677966, 1.74508474576271, 1.36677966101695, 1.22033898305085, 
1.06779661016949, 0.976271186440678, 2.45898305084746, 1.92203389830508, 
3.97830508474576, 4.20406779661017, 3.10576271186441, 2.44677966101695, 
2.0806779661017, 2.76406779661017, 4.91186440677966, 4.03322033898305, 
6.49220338983051, 5.66847457627119, 5.40610169491526, 4.33220338983051, 
3.64881355932203, 2.94101694915254, 2.67864406779661, 2.36135593220339, 
1.48881355932203, 2.04406779661017, 23.6440677966102, 37.9464406779661, 
14.448813559322, 5.11322033898305, 3.84406779661017, 3.19728813559322, 
2.78847457627119, 2.53220338983051, 3.84406779661017, 5.80271186440678, 
3.61830508474576, 2.85559322033898, 2.16610169491525, 1.87322033898305, 
1.76338983050847, 1.54372881355932, 1.44, 1.44, 1.01628, 3.0618, 
5.41836, 4.51764, 3.67524, 2.14704, 1.14156, 1.67990103092784, 
8.11269278350516, 10.943406185567, 13.7883711340206, 12.6268701030928, 
9.85494432989691, 7.08123711340206, 4.62284536082474, 2.8111175257732, 
1.8491381443299, 0.77436, 1.87056, 3.1212, 12.45132, 16.67952, 
16.76592, 14.42448, 5.51124, 1.72044, 1.07892, 0.413294845360825, 
5.91973608247423, 5.1323381443299, 17.6541030927835, 39.972024742268, 
49.7396783505155, 30.0066309278351, 9.22787628865979, 4.23983505154639, 
2.47798762886598, 0.92124, 2.15244, 1.88244, 2.2302, 2.15784, 
1.60164, 1.29168, 1.2366, 1.16856, 1.1016, 2.10032164948454, 
1.40734020618557, 1.53382268041237, 1.73868865979381, 5.0806762886598, 
6.41141443298969, 4.79920824742268, 7.93454845360825, 5.74337319587629, 
4.18995463917526, 1.49284948453608, 3.66799175257732, 5.78969072164949, 
6.35262680412371, 6.78373608247423, 14.0573690721649, 22.8541360824742, 
18.5590762886598, 14.053806185567, 10.9077773195876, 9.5271587628866, 
11.7735587628866, 19.5424329896907, 41.5486020618557, 45.8026886597938, 
45.7741855670103, 46.5918680412371, 46.2818969072165, 44.4470103092784, 
39.973806185567, 34.8681896907217, 29.5808659793814, 25.0738144329897, 
25.5334268041237, 3.29388865979381, 1.37471186440678, 1.84759322033898, 
2.41505084745763, 2.71830508474576, 3.74216949152542, 7.14325423728814, 
8.94264406779661, 8.24888135593221, 6.90650847457627, 4.24983050847458, 
4.62203389830509, 4.22664406779661, 21.8196610169492, 30.0075254237288, 
28.0562033898305, 28.8079322033898, 29.5962711864407, 31.1119322033898, 
0, 0, 20.8464494845361, 28.1753072164948, 33.238169072165, 35.7446597938144, 
42.2077360824742, 44.1370391752577, 42.1489484536083, 39.8758268041237, 
46.6773773195876, 48.5496742268041, 46.9374680412371, 39.6424577319588, 
32.1586144329897, 26.5933855670103, 30.6693278350516, 29.2370474226804, 
26.326169072165, 22.578012371134, 20.6006103092784, 17.2194309278351, 
49.9926432989691, 53.1725195876289, 39.4856907216495, 25.8166762886598, 
21.5768412371134, 18.2134762886598, 14.6131793814433, 12.1066886597938, 
10.0900948453608, 8.26945979381443, 6.90309278350516, 6.38291134020619, 
5.51712989690722, 4.48389278350515, 3.54863505154639, 2.85209072164948, 
0.469830508474576, 0.958576271186441, 1.51505084745763, 2.85864406779661, 
5.58976271186441, 7.85898305084746, 10.9940338983051, 14.4280677966102, 
17.6753898305085, 18.7541694915254, 20.6377627118644, 31.1863728813559, 
34.2561355932203, 33.7844745762712, 22.4664406779661, 18.8456949152542, 
16.6856949152542, 14.3188474576271, 11.7421016949153, 9.66874576271186, 
8.64976271186441, 8.22630508474576, 8.19274576271186, 7.80406779661017, 
6.88576271186441, 6.0046779661017, 1.63180206185567, 3.53794639175258, 
5.63470515463918, 6.45951340206186, 6.80511340206186, 6.85499381443299, 
6.76592164948454, 6.8834969072165, 6.96188041237113, 7.01176082474227, 
2.33012783505155, 0.698325773195876, 0.608338983050847, 0.968949152542373, 
1.18677966101695, 1.34542372881356, 1.48027118644068, 1.53701694915254, 
1.60352542372881, 1.70481355932203, 1.71884745762712, 1.74203389830509, 
0.619525423525424, 0.254491525220339, 3.94524, 22.9932, 30.01428, 
32.14944, 32.39676, 30.53916, 27.67824, 20.0016, 10.14552, 9.44352, 
8.74152, 8.36352, 7.98552, 7.28352, 7.39152, 8.60004, 15.5736, 
18.28764, 21.86676, 31.9302, 32.54796, 32.64192, 32.7456, 31.88052, 
30.55644, 28.94832, 26.84664, 20.17116, 16.36848, 14.50224, 14.715, 
12.81312, 10.94688, 10.31292, 8.00496, 5.4972, 2.3652, 1.17504, 
6.84074226804124, 19.8025237113402, 31.0416494845361, 38.2921237113402, 
32.484618556701, 22.1379958762887, 15.4896494845361, 11.5063422680412, 
9.08714226804124, 7.59251134020619, 7.09014432989691, 6.8834969072165, 
6.912, 7.01176082474227, 10.1862927835052, 11.5936329896907, 
16.3714639175258, 21.8975010309278, 27.1491958762887, 51.8524701030928, 
51.2859711340206, 50.7533195876289, 48.2414845360825, 43.7807505154639, 
38.2511505154639, 31.8237030927835, 25.4710762886598, 22.0578309278351, 
20.6023917525773, 19.1950515463918, 17.8785649484536, 16.530012371134, 
14.689781443299, 13.1684288659794, 11.5152494845361, 10.1684783505155, 
8.9107793814433, 7.75818556701031, 6.94228453608248, 9.84247422680412, 
4.17926597938144, 2.80221030927835, 2.8912824742268, 1.51092, 
2.14488, 2.19564, 3.56184, 4.48308, 3.37068, 4.38264, 4.92264, 
9.35496, 6.99732, 6.72624, 7.63992, 9.95652, 12.2472, 19.46376, 
23.54724, 23.90796, 22.869, 20.17224, 16.28532, 12.02472, 9.30528, 
10.37664, 11.87136, 11.65428, 10.8162, 9.41328, 7.98552, 6.20352, 
4.21956, 1.84788, 3.39186804123711, 3.59851546391753, 4.91678350515464, 
7.40545979381443, 7.11864742268041, 7.78847010309278, 6.47020206185567, 
7.86685360824742, 8.48501443298969, 10.1880742268041, 9.04616907216495, 
9.24390927835052, 11.1108618556701, 15.5252783505155, 19.757987628866, 
24.9063587628866, 26.0589525773196, 24.3594556701031, 20.4955051546392, 
16.2467628865979, 13.4017979381443, 15.2705319587629, 15.4094845360825, 
14.6630597938144, 13.1969319587629, 10.7278515463918, 9.35079587628866, 
8.54558350515464, 6.7160412371134, 5.31938969072165, 4.15967010309278, 
3.75706391752577, 1.55628, 1.70856, 1.5282, 1.60164, 1.5282, 
1.54548, 6.07932, 6.50484, 2.42892, 4.39992, 3.8826, 2.92032, 
1.7982, 1.19124, 0.9882, 0.8532, 0.6642, 0.56268, 2.48689484536082, 
4.97557113402062, 8.57586804123712, 9.12633402061856, 8.16257319587629, 
5.5759175257732, 3.90492371134021, 3.64839587628866, 2.74520412371134, 
2.73451546391753, 5.93933195876289, 5.20003298969072, 4.45538969072165, 
2.91978556701031, 2.28202886597938, 2.09319587628866, 1.79035051546392, 
1.31826804123711, 1.32717525773196, 1.01628, 13.74408, 23.0742, 
22.98888, 14.02056, 11.75256, 22.37652, 27.73116, 30.67632, 32.99724, 
33.52104, 32.4486, 31.1742, 30.03156, 30.49812, 30.86424, 30.618, 
30.15576, 4.3038, 6.0534, 6.1074, 5.19696, 4.93776, 5.73048, 
5.2542, 4.41072, 3.4722, 2.5164, 1.86516, 1.18584, 0.89532, 1.96671340206186, 
17.6558845360825, 24.8921072164948, 15.9207587628866, 21.7371711340206, 
37.1662515463918, 46.8590845360825, 52.4813195876289, 50.3079587628866, 
44.0586556701031, 40.1804536082474, 42.6762556701031, 44.1530721649485, 
41.9120164948454, 40.6721319587629, 38.9049402061856, 32.7464907216495, 
25.2555216494845, 8.49570309278351, 9.50221855670103, 9.95292371134021, 
8.37990927835052, 8.90009072164949, 7.42327422680412, 6.17626391752577, 
4.87759175257732, 4.43579381443299, 3.67689896907217, 2.92156701030928, 
2.19295670103093, 1.85804536082474, 1.998, 4.4226, 18.18504, 
24.28272, 25.28172, 32.33196, 31.95936, 30.96036, 29.64384, 28.47852, 
28.20096, 25.34652, 17.61696, 11.42316, 6.7932, 5.07384, 3.4236, 
2.03472, 2.68285360824742, 7.66020618556701, 19.5531216494845, 
27.3059628865979, 43.7647175257732, 47.5235628865979, 45.1880907216495, 
41.1549030927835, 36.4429855670103, 35.9833731958763, 28.3231670103093, 
21.8030845360825, 14.6042721649485, 9.52894020618557, 6.12638350515464, 
3.9744, 0.77544, 22.32036, 28.8846, 31.6332, 31.12776, 29.94192, 
28.4256, 22.98996, 14.29812, 31.0122, 30.88692, 29.37492, 26.5626, 
16.41276, 9.27072, 4.66992, 2.4948, 25.1046, 21.20904, 14.75064, 
9.23076, 5.46264, 10.05696, 7.92072, 4.49496, 1.3538969072165, 
31.5885525773196, 44.9475958762887, 49.6702020618557, 39.4215587628866, 
36.2488082474227, 17.1588618556701, 44.3793154639175, 41.2635711340206, 
29.434787628866, 16.2752659793814, 6.76592164948454, 2.6151587628866, 
24.4182432989691, 15.9599505154639, 8.04499793814433, 9.81397113402062, 
7.17743505154639, 4.10978969072165, 2.22804, 24.17256, 11.57544, 
25.20288, 31.48632, 29.17944, 25.07868, 12.37356, 6.09012, 3.30372, 
4.11691546391753, 16.8471092783505, 32.8836618556701, 45.7100536082474, 
26.4348371134021, 13.1292371134021, 4.67985154639175, 0.7614, 
9.73188, 3.92688, 1.0908, 1.20603711340206, 9.32407422680413, 
2.62762886597938, 4.18608, 1.41156, 1.69415257731959, 1.67277525773196, 
1.70208, 12.96864, 21.91968, 26.80128, 31.78224, 32.5836, 32.05008, 
30.483, 29.05416, 27.26352, 25.81956, 24.6996, 23.19408, 22.76532, 
30.83508, 34.08156, 34.94232, 35.49852, 6.95196, 2.83605773195876, 
18.607175257732, 33.7779463917526, 51.5068701030928, 49.7129567010309, 
44.9030597938144, 34.7256742268041, 25.0381855670103, 23.9942597938144, 
24.1029278350516, 39.5907958762887, 53.2330886597938, 54.4587216494846, 
55.3209402061856, 56.2490721649485, 58.5970144329897, 57.6742268041237, 
55.2211793814433, 5.97674226804124, 2.86416, 19.47132, 21.75444, 
19.97028, 15.87384, 11.47392, 8.4888, 6.05772, 4.00032, 2.28744, 
1.3824, 4.09019381443299, 23.3458144329897, 20.3280494845361, 
14.5062927835052, 9.66611134020619, 6.48089072164949, 3.36336494845361, 
2.03618969072165, 1.88832989690722, 29.05848, 34.83, 34.47684, 
33.16896, 31.7304, 29.98296, 2.55096, 53.2348701030928, 58.2086597938144, 
55.700387628866, 50.1761319587629, 44.3935670103093, 36.0439422680412, 
29.2762391752577, 21.8814680412371, 15.8726597938144, 3.13712164948454
), event = c("03262020", "03262020", "03262020", "03262020", 
"03262020", "03262020", "03262020", "03292020", "03292020", "03292020", 
"03292020", "03292020", "03292020", "03292020", "03292020", "03292020", 
"03292020", "03292020", "03292020", "03292020", "03292020", "03292020", 
"03292020", "03292020", "03292020", "04132020", "04132020", "04132020", 
"04132020", "04132020", "04132020", "04132020", "04132020", "04132020", 
"04132020", "04272020", "04272020", "04272020", "04272020", "04272020", 
"04272020", "04272020", "04272020", "04272020", "04272020", "05122020", 
"05122020", "05122020", "05122020", "05122020", "05122020", "05122020", 
"05122020", "05122020", "05122020", "05122020", "05122020", "05122020", 
"05122020", "05122020", "05122020", "05122020", "08052020", "08052020", 
"08052020", "08052020", "08052020", "08052020", "08052020", "08052020", 
"08052020", "08052020", "08052020", "08052020", "08052020", "08052020", 
"08052020", "08052020", "08052020", "08052020", "08052020", "08052020", 
"09302020", "09302020", "09302020", "09302020", "09302020", "09302020", 
"09302020", "09302020", "09302020", "09302020", "09302020", "09302020", 
"09302020", "09302020", "09302020", "09302020", "09302020", "09302020", 
"09302020", "09302020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", 
"12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", 
"12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", 
"12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", 
"12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", 
"12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", 
"12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12012020", 
"12012020", "12012020", "12012020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", 
"12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", 
"12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", 
"12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", 
"12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", 
"12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", 
"12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", 
"12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", 
"12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", 
"12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", 
"12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", "12252020", 
"12252020", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", 
"01172021", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", 
"01172021", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", 
"01172021", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", "01172021", 
"01172021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", 
"03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "03112021", "04162021", "04162021", 
"04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", 
"04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", 
"04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", 
"04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", 
"04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", 
"04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", 
"04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", 
"04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", 
"04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", 
"04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", "04162021", 
"04162021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", 
"04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", 
"04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", 
"04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", 
"04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", 
"04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", "04222021", 
"04222021", "04222021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", 
"04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", 
"04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", 
"04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", 
"04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", 
"04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", 
"04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", 
"04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", 
"04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", 
"04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", 
"04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "04302021", "05062021", "05062021", 
"05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", 
"05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", 
"05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", 
"05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", 
"05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", "05062021", 
"05062021", "05062021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", 
"07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", 
"07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", 
"07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", 
"07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", 
"07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", 
"07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", 
"07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07022021", "07092021", "07092021", 
"07092021", "07092021", "07092021", "07092021", "07092021", "07092021", 
"07092021", "07092021", "07092021", "07092021", "07092021", "07092021", 
"07092021", "07092021", "07092021", "07132021", "07132021", "07132021", 
"07132021", "07132021", "07132021", "07132021", "07142021", "07142021", 
"07142021", "07142021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", 
"07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", 
"07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", 
"07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", 
"07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", 
"07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", 
"07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07182021", "07192021", "07192021", 
"07192021", "07192021", "07192021", "07192021", "07192021", "07192021", 
"07192021", "07192021", "07192021", "07192021", "07192021", "07192021", 
"07192021", "07192021", "07192021", "07192021", "07192021", "07192021", 
"07212021", "07212021", "07212021", "07212021", "07212021", "07212021", 
"07212021", "07212021", "07212021", "07212021", "07212021", "07212021", 
"07212021", "07212021", "07212021", "07212021", "07212021")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-657L))
```

Comment: Using your first code every `tidied` column has 2 rows. Check `fitted.models$tidied[[1]]` and `fitted.models$tidied[[2]]`. So when you `unnest` the number of rows increases.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @Ronak Shah's note in the comments, your code produces a data frame where each element in the `tidied` column is itself a data frame with two rows. For example:

[image]

Since unnesting flattens your list-column of data frames back into regular columns (see `?tidyr::nest`), it is expected that the unnested data frame would have `N` rows, where `N` equals `nrow` of each nested data frame (i.e., 2) times the number of nested data frames (i.e., 22). If we examine the first few rows of the unnested data frame:

[image]

You see that each unique `event` ID has a row with `(Intercept)` in the `term` column and a row with `Flow` in the `term` column, as expected.